# Run a method after Tomcat server starts

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, tomcat

I need to start/run method (3 methods declared inside a class) only after Tomcat Server has started and ran. I went over several threads suggesting using `Servlet`s (listener class) in `web.xml`. The problem is my class which implements `ServletContextListene`r runs even before completion of loading Tomcat Server.

Note: My `web.xml` is already tagged to dispatcher servlet looking for any REST API calls.

Ex (Below are few logs to help you understand more):

```
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Oct 26, 2018 6:20:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext   
.
{{ Connect with MYSQL }} 
.
Oct 26, 2018 6:20:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
.
18:20:51.394 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/user/someMethod],methods=[POST],produces=[application/xml || application/json]}" onto public java.util.ArrayList<com.x.y.z.User> com.z.y.controllers.UserController.deleteUser(com.x.y.z.User)
    18:20:52.090 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Oct 26 18:20:50 IST 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
    18:20:52.181 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Oct 26 18:20:50 IST 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
    18:20:52.394 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 2041 ms
    Oct 26, 2018 6:20:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
    Oct 26, 2018 6:20:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"]
    Oct 26, 2018 6:20:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 27236 ms

{{ I want to call methods after Tomcat starts }}
```

When I initialize the class under `ServletContextListener` the below log throws up.

```
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Oct 26, 2018 6:22:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
.
.
{{ Connect with MYSQL }}
.
18:22:16.461 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6635 ms
**MyClass - myFileWatcher()
The above thread has started**
.
.
```

As my method has thread it gets stuck even before Tomcat starts completely (the thread should start only when this displays '*INFO: Server startup in 27236 ms*').

Note: Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Have you tried to configure a servlet (that contains your initialization code) with <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> in web.xml?

Comment: @LeandroLuque yes, that too shows up the same output as Listener.

Comment: Rishi, does the @lealceldeiro answer solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [`@Bean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html) which provides a [`CommandLineRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html). Something [like this](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/47d9669dbf87ae00b1bff85d99c572834b2d6c2b/server/src/main/java/com/gms/Application.java#L43):

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(SomeAppService someAppService) {
    return strings -> {
        // do something with someAppService
        // this code will run just after the application has fully started
    };
}
```

There are other ways to do this. You can read some related articles here:

- [Spring Boot: ApplicationRunner and CommandLineRunner](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-applicationrunner-and-commandlinerunne)
- [How to Use CommandLineRunner in Spring Boot Application](https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/spring-boot/how-to-use-commandlinerunner-in-spring-boot-application.html)
- [Spring boot – CommandLineRunner interface example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/command-line-runner-interface-example/)

Comment: Sorry, as I couldn't reply earlier. Many thanks for the answer. I tried implementing but failed to as I need to go through Spring boot more. Implementing this might solve the issue, but is it possible to solve it by going through a more classic way (using a thread or so)?  Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: How does this fail? Can you provide me with some more details? If you have a github repo in which I could take a look at, that would be great!